# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

Собственно форма входа на сайт
Вылезает ошибка которая не позволяет выполнить скрипт,не понятно как у меня может быть тип null.
Как исправить чтобы все работало?

```js
var link = document.querySelector(".login");
var popup = document.querySelector(".modal-content");
var close = document.querySelector(".modal-content-close");


link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  popup.classList.add("modal-content-show");

});

close.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  popup.classList.remove("modal-content-show");
});
```

```css
.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -230px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 50px 80px;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #000;
  background: #f8f3f0 url("../img/bg2.jpg") repeat;
  display: none;
}

.modal-content-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -34px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content-show {
  display: block;
}

.modal-content-close::before,
.modal-content-close::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 19px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.modal-content-close::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal-content-close::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.modal-content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.modal-content p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.modal-content .login-form {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.login-form input[type="text"],
.login-form input[type="password"] {
  width: 236px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #f9f6f3;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  outline: none;
}

.login-form input:focus {
  border-color: #663d15;
}

.login-form input.icon-user {
  background-image: url("../img/man.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% -504px;
}

.login-form input.icon-password {
  background-image: url("./img/lock.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% -45px;
}

.login-form .restore {
  float: right;
  color: #000;
}

.login-form .btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.login-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.login-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]+.checkbox-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.login-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkbox-indicator::before,
.login-checkbox input[tupe="checkbox"]:checked+.checkbox-indicator::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.login-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkbox-indicator::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.login-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkbox-indicator::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="user-block">
  <a href="#" class="login">Вход</a>
</div>
<div class="modal-content">
  <button class="modal-content-close" type="button" title="закрыть">Закрыть</button>
  <h2 class="modal-content-title">Личный кабинет</h2>
  <p>Введите свой логин и пароль</p>
  <form class="login-form" action="" method="post">
    <input class="icon-user" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин">
    <input class="icon-password" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
    <label class="login-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="remember">
     <span class="checkbox-indicator"></span>
     Запомните меня 
     </label>
    <a href="#" class="restore">Я забыл пароль !</a>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Войти</button>
  </form>
  <div class="modal-content-map">
    <button class="modal-content-close" type="button" title="закрыть">
      Закрыть
     </button>

  </div>
```

Comment: у Вас нет элемента, который бы соответствовал CSS-селектору `.login`

Comment: Собственно забыл вставить,но он есть

Comment: Тогда, как вариант, скрипт выполняется до того, как элемент появляется на странице

Comment: я сделал ссылкой на отдельный файл,а не в index.html

Comment: Как оформлен скрипт (отдельным файлом или в самом HTML-е) - не суть важно в данном случае. Важно когда он исполняется. Если он вставлен, например, в `head`, то выполнится он до того, как появится `div` в `body`

Comment: Добавьте атрибут defer к тэгу script который подключает js файл.

Comment: Получается надо все время прописывать путь к скрипту в конце в body?Или писать defer?

Comment: Всем спасибо,хотя бы с defer работает

Comment: @Frallen обычно код, завязанный на работу с DOM, оборачивают в обработчик события document ready. Посмотрите в эту сторону

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оформлен скрипт (отдельным файлом или в самом HTML-е) - не суть важно в данном случае. Важно когда он исполняется. Если он вставлен, например, в head, то выполнится он до того, как появится div в body

Comment: Вы дали ответ? Если да, то дополните его так, что бы было сразу понятно, что ваша проблема решена.